# Timer resetting again on pressing pause button and not running in background

Tags: android, android-service

I have created an `up count counter` for that I am running a background service so that the counter will run in the background even after the app being killed. But when the app is killed, the counter begins counting from the starting and when I press the pause button and play it again, the counter again begins counting as before from the starting. Below is the code for my service and Activity. Please help me out.

```
package io.funswitch.gymmon.Services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Locale;

import static io.funswitch.gymmon.Fragments.CheckOutFragment.running;

    public class TimerService  extends Service {
    private Intent intent;
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.javacodegeeks.android.androidtimerexample.MainActivity";

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private long initial_time;
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initial_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
        }
    };

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - initial_time;

        int timer = (int) timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
        intent.putExtra("time", timer);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

CheckoutActivity.java

```
 package io.funswitch.gymmon.activities;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

import io.funswitch.gymmon.Fragments.CheckOutFragment;
import io.funswitch.gymmon.R;
import io.funswitch.gymmon.Services.TimerService;

public class CheckOutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Boolean exit = false;
    ImageView play_pause, play;
    private int milliseconds;
    public boolean running;
    TextView timer;
    int time;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out);
        play_pause = findViewById(R.id.pause_play);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
        play = findViewById(R.id.play);
        play_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        time = getIntent().getIntExtra("time", 0);

//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//            CheckOutFragment stepsDetailActivityFragment = new CheckOutFragment();
//            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
//                    .add(R.id.check_out_frame, stepsDetailActivityFragment)
//                    .commit();
//
//        }
//        int time = getIntent().getIntExtra("time", 0);
//        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        bundle.putInt("time", time);
//// set Fragmentclass Arguments
//        CheckOutFragment fragobj = new CheckOutFragment();
//        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == play_pause) {
            if (running) {
//                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
//                sharedPreferences.getInt("tim", 0);
                stopService(new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, TimerService.class));
                running = false;
                play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_button);
            } else {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
                sharedPreferences.getInt("timee", 0);
                running = true;
                play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TimerService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
                startService(new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, TimerService.class));

            }
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            runTimer(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        running = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, TimerService.class);
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TimerService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
//        running = false;
//        stopService(new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, TimerService.class));
//        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);


    }


    public void runTimer(Intent intent) {
        time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);
        int hour = time / 3600;
        int mins = time / 60;
        int secs = time % 60;
        String timerTask = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, mins, secs);
        timer.setText(timerTask);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("tim", time);
        editor.apply();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (exit) {
            finish(); // finish activity
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 2 * 1000);

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

//        Intent intent = new Intent(CheckOutActivity.this, TimerService.class);
//        startService(intent);
//        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TimerService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }


}
```

I have also tried to save values in sharedPreferences and retrieving it when play button clicks but it's not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Youn need to save your counter in sharedprefrences and restore the counter value on service restart

In your `CheckOutActivity`

```
    @Override
            protected void onStop() {
        // save counter(time) value to sharedprefrences 
        running = false;
        stopService(intent)
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }

        int time;

 public void runTimer(Intent intent){
        time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);
        int hour = time/3600;
        int mins = time / 60;
        int secs = time % 60;
        timer.setText(String.format(Locale.US,"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, mins, secs));
    }
```

In `TimerService`

```
int counter;
     @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
        //set counter to value from sharedprefrences 
    }

private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - initial_time;

        int timer = (int) timeInMilliseconds / 1000;
        intent.putExtra("time", timer+counter);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it little more I am very new to sharedPrefernces and services can you please tell me the little lines of code so that I can pursue ahead.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2017/07/25/android-service-lifecycle-and-working/

Comment: After setting initial_time value to sharedPref where should I retrive those values? and the pref I save in onStop where should I retrieve them too?

Comment: In `TimerService onCreate`  check my answer

Comment: so I have to save counter value in sharedPref in onStop and call it from onCreate of TimerService?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176457/discussion-between-divyank-vijayvergiya-and-prashant17).

Comment: No it's not working it causes same problem as before

Comment: Have anyone able to found an issue ?